# Rearranging mysql data to fit a 4 column table where each row has a different number of columns (using colspan)

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, html-table

I'm trying to put together a photo portfolio for a friend consisting of landscape and profile photos.
I've got an SQL table with the photo details including a column stating whether the photo is horizontal or vertical.

The table rows are grouped into 3: 
1st row of the table showing 4 vertical pictures. 
2nd row showing 1 vertical picture, 1 horizontal picture with a colspan of 2, followed by another vertical picture. 
3rd row showing 4 vertical pictures.

Repeating the above pattern as required.

I can get it to limit the table to 4 columns using the below code and add a colspan for the horizontal photos, but it's not in the right order - it also misses the first record off.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
<?php
$cols = 4; // number of columns
$c = 1;
echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr>";
while ($row_photos = mysql_fetch_assoc($photos)) {
    if ($row_photos['photo_type'] == "Vertical") {
    echo "<td>".stripslashes($row_photos['photo_file'])."&nbsp;".stripslashes($row_photos['photo_type'])."</td>";
    }
    elseif ($row_photos['photo_type'] == "Horizontal") {
    echo "<td colspan=\"2\">".stripslashes($row_photos['photo_file'])."&nbsp;".stripslashes($row_photos['photo_type'])."</td>";
    $c++;
    }
    if ($c == $cols) {
        echo "</tr><tr>";
        $c = 1;
    } else { $c++; }
}
echo "</tr>" ;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: You should simply put the images there and set padding.  No tables needed!

Comment: You want to change c to 0. Otherwise after the first picture c is 2, after the second picture c is 3 and after the third picture it is already at 4 and creates a new row. For the order the reason could be in your SQL query?

Comment: What you are describing requires the records from the database to be in exactly the right order. Are you sure they are?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems:

1. @Dan is right, you need to change `$c` to 0 or use `>` instead of `==`;
2. You are adding 2 to `$c` in every loop instead of 1, once before the `if` statement and once in the `else` statement;
3. Your loop will fail if the order of the records from the database is not exactly right. I would recommend looping through all your records once to generate 2 arrays, one with horizontal photos and one with vertical photos. Then you can adjust your loop and just pick a photo from the appropriate array.